How to resolve "context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy"?
I tried to create a robot in Gazebo using .xacro, .gazebo, and .launch files, and everything seems fine. However, when I run Gazebo, I encounter the message context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy.
From what I've found, it seems related to map creation. Since I plan to add LIDAR functionality for detection later on, I'm concerned that this issue might affect map creation. Currently, none of my three files contain any code related to map creation. How did this issue occur, and will it affect adding LIDAR functionality in the future? Here are the three files: .xacro, .gazebo, and .launch.
.xacro
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- ###################################### -->
<!-- DESCRIPTION OF THE 4-WHEELED ROBOT     -->
<!-- ###################################### -->
 
<robot name="mecanum_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
 
  <!-- Body dimensions -->
  <xacro:property name="body_link_x_dim" value="1"/>
  <xacro:property name="body_link_y_dim" value="0.6"/>
  <xacro:property name="body_link_z_dim" value="0.3"/>
 
  <!-- Wheel dimensions -->
  <xacro:property name="wheel_link_radius" value="0.15"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_link_length" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_link_z_location" value="-0.1"/>
 
  <!-- Material density -->
  <xacro:property name="body_density" value="2710.0"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_density" value="2710.0"/>
 
  <!-- Pi constant -->
  <xacro:property name="pi_constant" value="3.14159265"/>
 
  <!-- Robot body and wheel mass -->
  <xacro:property name="body_mass" value="${body_density*body_link_x_dim*body_link_y_dim*body_link_z_dim}"/>
  <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="${wheel_density*pi_constant*wheel_link_radius*wheel_link_radius*wheel_link_length}"/>
 
  <!-- Moments of inertia of the wheel -->
  <xacro:property name="Iz_wheel" value="${0.5*wheel_mass*wheel_link_radius*wheel_link_radius}"/>
  <xacro:property name="I_wheel" value="${(1.0/12.0)*wheel_mass*(3.0*wheel_link_radius*wheel_link_radius+wheel_link_length*wheel_link_length)}"/>
 
  <!-- This macro defines the complete inertial section of the wheel -->
  <!-- It is used later in the code                                   -->
  <xacro:macro name="inertia_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="${wheel_mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${I_wheel}" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="${I_wheel}" iyz="0" izz="${Iz_wheel}" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>
 
  <!-- Include the file that defines extra Gazebo options and motion control driver -->
  <xacro:include filename="$(find ros_car)/urdf/robot.gazebo" />
 
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- DEFINE LINKS, JOINTS    -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
 
  <!-- Dummy link otherwise Gazebo will complain -->
  <link name="dummy"/>
  <joint name="dummy_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="dummy"/>
    <child link="body_link"/>
  </joint>
 
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- START: BODY link of the robot    -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <link name="body_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${body_link_x_dim} ${body_link_y_dim} ${body_link_z_dim}" />
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${body_link_x_dim} ${body_link_y_dim} ${body_link_z_dim}" />
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="${body_mass}"/>
      <inertia ixx="${(1/12)*body_mass*(body_link_y_dim*body_link_y_dim+body_link_z_dim*body_link_z_dim)}"
               ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(1/12)*body_mass*(body_link_x_dim*body_link_x_dim+body_link_z_dim*body_link_z_dim)}"
               iyz="0"
               izz="${(1/12)*body_mass*(body_link_x_dim*body_link_x_dim+body_link_y_dim*body_link_y_dim)}" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- END: BODY link of the robot    -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
 
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- START: Back right wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <joint name="wheel1_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="body_link"/>
    <child link="wheel1_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${-body_link_x_dim/2+1.2*wheel_link_radius} ${-body_link_y_dim/2-wheel_link_length/2} ${wheel_link_z_location}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000" velocity="1000"/>
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
  </joint>
 
  <link name="wheel1_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertia_wheel/>
  </link>
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- END: Back right wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
 
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- START: Back left wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <joint name="wheel2_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="body_link"/>
    <child link="wheel2_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${-body_link_x_dim/2+1.2*wheel_link_radius} ${body_link_y_dim/2+wheel_link_length/2} ${wheel_link_z_location}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000" velocity="1000"/>
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
  </joint>
 
  <link name="wheel2_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertia_wheel/>
  </link>
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- END: Back left wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
 
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- START: Front right wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <joint name="wheel3_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="body_link"/>
    <child link="wheel3_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${body_link_x_dim/2-1.2*wheel_link_radius} ${-body_link_y_dim/2-wheel_link_length/2} ${wheel_link_z_location}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000" velocity="1000"/>
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
  </joint>
 
  <link name="wheel3_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertia_wheel/>
  </link>
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- END: Front right wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
 
  <!-- ###################################### -->
  <!-- START: Front left wheel of the robot and the joint -->
  <!-- ###################################### -->
 
  <joint name="wheel4_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="body_link"/>
    <child link="wheel4_link"/>
    <origin xyz="${body_link_x_dim/2-1.2*wheel_link_radius} ${body_link_y_dim/2+wheel_link_length/2} ${wheel_link_z_location}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000" velocity="1000"/>
    <dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
  </joint>
 
  <link name="wheel4_link">
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="1.570795 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${wheel_link_length}" radius="${wheel_link_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertia_wheel/>
  </link>
<!-- ###################################### -->
<!-- END: Front left wheel of the robot and the joint -->
<!-- ###################################### -->
 
</robot>

.gazebo
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- #################################################### -->
<!-- GAZEBO ADDITIONAL DESCRIPTION OF THE 4-WHEELED ROBOT -->
<!-- #################################################### -->
<robot>
 
  <!-- mu1 and mu2 are friction coefficients -->
  <gazebo reference="body_link">
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
  </gazebo>
 
  <gazebo reference="wheel1_link">
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
 
  <gazebo reference="wheel2_link">
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
 
  <gazebo reference="wheel3_link">
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
 
  <gazebo reference="wheel4_link">
    <mu1>0.2</mu1>
    <mu2>0.2</mu2>
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
  </gazebo>
 
  <!-- Controller for the 4-wheeled robot -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="skid_steer_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so">
      <!-- Control update rate in Hz -->
      <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
      <!-- Leave this empty otherwise, there will be problems with sending control commands -->
      <robotNamespace> </robotNamespace>
      <!-- Robot kinematics -->
      <leftFrontJoint>wheel4_joint</leftFrontJoint>
      <rightFrontJoint>wheel3_joint</rightFrontJoint>
      <leftRearJoint>wheel2_joint</leftRearJoint>
      <rightRearJoint>wheel1_joint</rightRearJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>${body_link_y_dim+wheel_link_length}</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>${wheel_link_radius}</wheelDiameter>
 
      <!-- Maximum torque which the wheels can produce, in Nm, defaults to 5 Nm -->
      <torque>1000</torque>
 
      <!-- Topic to receive geometry_msgs/Twist message commands, defaults to 'cmd_vel' -->
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <!-- Topic to publish nav_msgs/Odometry messages, defaults to 'odom' -->
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <!-- Odometry frame, defaults to 'odom' -->
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <!-- Robot frame to calculate odometry from, defaults to 'base_footprint' -->
      <robotBaseFrame>dummy</robotBaseFrame>
      <!-- Set to true to publish transforms for the wheel links, defaults to false -->
      <publishWheelTF>true</publishWheelTF>
      <!-- Set to true to publish transforms for the wheel links, defaults to true -->
      <publishOdom>true</publishOdom>
      <!-- Set to true to publish sensor_msgs/JointState on /joint_state for the wheel joints, defaults to false -->
      <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
      <!-- This part is required by Gazebo -->
      <covariance_x>0.0001</covariance_x>
      <covariance_y>0.0001</covariance_y>
      <covariance_yaw>0.01</covariance_yaw>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
 
</robot>

.launch
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- #################################################### -->
<!-- LAUNCH FILE FOR THE GAZEBO SIMULATION OF THE 4-WHEELED ROBOT -->
<!-- #################################################### -->
 
<launch>
 
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="true"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>
 
<!-- Load the robot description -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find ros_car)/urdf/robot.xacro'"/>
<!-- Robot state publisher node -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
 
<!-- Spawn the model -->
<node name="urdf_spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-urdf -model ros_car -param robot_description" />
 
</launch>

